# How to add empty image to RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using a RecyclerView and I don't want images in some of my ViewHolders.

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};
```

I am passing my images in an int array. Is it possible to pass in a blank image / null image in this array so that the image won't render?

As suggested by @muhammad-ahmed I have edited my Integer array and added this to my onBindViewHolder function.

```
Integer[] images = {null, R.drawable.image2};

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull thisViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (images_data[position] == null) {
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.image.setImageResource(post_images_data[position]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reference type/ Box Type

```
Integer[] post_images = {R.drawable.animal_0, R.drawable.animal_1,
                     null, R.drawable.animal_3};
```

and in RecyclerView ViewHolder check if an image is null hide the ImageView

Comment: Thanks! How do I check if an image is null? is it if(imageViewOne.getDrawable() == null)? And by hiding, do you mean setting the Image to GONE?

Answer (score 0):

how about you set up a placeholder image in the item's xml? you will have an image to render in the case the array position is null. Every time the view gets inflated, you will have a placeholder image.